# Ionic 3 use third party libs only in one page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm have an Ionic 3 app and in my login page I want to use the particles.js lib (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-particle).

If I import it on the app.module.ts, it works fine, but then it will be loaded for all my application right?

I'd like to use it ONLY on my login page. When the page is different, particles.js should not be loaded.

I've tried to import it on my login.ts but then it does not work.
I've tried to import it to the login.module.ts as well, but had the same result

login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage 
{
    myStyle: Object = {};
    myParams: Object = {};
    width: number = 100;
    height: number = 100;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) 
    {
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() 
    {
        this.myStyle = {
            'position': 'fixed',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'z-index': -1,
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'right': 0,
            'bottom': 0,
        };

        this.myParams = {
                particles: {
                    number: {
                        value: 200,
                    },
                    color: {
                        value: '#242A31'
                    },
                    shape: {
                        type: 'triangle',
                    },
            }
        };
    }
}
```

login.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './login';
import { ParticlesModule } from 'angular-particle';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginPage,
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
        ParticlesModule
    ]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

login.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Elly</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content id="page-content" padding>
    <particles [params]="myParams" [style]="myStyle" [width]="width" [height]="height"></particles>

    <!-- <ion-card>
        meu card
    </ion-card> -->
</ion-content>
```

The error

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'params' since it isn't a known property of 'particles'. ("

&lt;ion-content id="page-content" padding&gt;
    &lt;particles [ERROR -&gt;][params]="myParams" [style]="myStyle" [width]="width" [height]="height"&gt;&lt;/particles&gt;

    &lt;!-- &lt;ion-c"): ng:///AppModule/LoginPage.html@7:15
Can't bind to 'width' since it isn't a known property of 'particles'. ("

&lt;ion-content id="page-content" padding&gt;
    &lt;particles [params]="myParams" [style]="myStyle" [ERROR -&gt;][width]="width" [height]="height"&gt;&lt;/particles&gt;

    &lt;!-- &lt;ion-card&gt;
"): ng:///AppModule/LoginPage.html@7:53
Can't bind to 'height' since it isn't a known property of 'particles'. ("ent id="page-content" padding&gt;
    &lt;particles [params]="myParams" [style]="myStyle" [width]="width" [ERROR -&gt;][height]="height"&gt;&lt;/particles&gt;

    &lt;!-- &lt;ion-card&gt;
"): ng:///AppModule/LoginPage.html@7:69
'particles' is not a known element:
1. If 'particles' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

&lt;ion-content id="page-content" padding&gt;
    [ERROR -&gt;]&lt;particles [params]="myParams" [style]="myStyle" [width]="width" [height]="height"&gt;&lt;/particles&gt;

    "): ng:///AppModule/LoginPage.html@7:4
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: I believe, If you put your login controller in a separate module then you can lazy load it.  This will avoid loading it when the app opens but only when that login controller is used.